# Inconsistent UIButton title height when run on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uibutton

I have two buttons with titles that are changed at runtime, and the height of the buttons resize to accommodate the title. On the iPhone this works perfectly, even when the title runs to two or three lines. However, on the iPad the spacing is inconsistent. Sometimes a one-line title will have the height that a two-line title would have, and sometimes it is correct. Sometimes both buttons on a page are spaced correctly, sometimes both are too big, and sometimes there is one of each.

Here is a sample of the code that sets the text:

```
[a setTitle:@"Yes, quite often" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[b setTitle:@"No, not very often" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And this manages the spacing (a and b are the two buttons):

```
a.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[a.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
b.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[b.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

    [a setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0)];
    [a sizeToFit];
    a.frame = CGRectMake(a.frame.origin.x, a.frame.origin.y, 200, a.titleLabel.frame.size.height+20);

    [b setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0)];
    [b sizeToFit];
    b.frame = CGRectMake(b.frame.origin.x, b.frame.origin.y, 200, b.titleLabel.frame.size.height+20);
}
else {

    [a setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 8.0)];
    [a sizeToFit];
    a.frame = CGRectMake(a.frame.origin.x, a.frame.origin.y, 300, a.titleLabel.frame.size.height+30);

    [b setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 8.0)];
    [b sizeToFit];
    b.frame = CGRectMake(b.frame.origin.x, b.frame.origin.y, 300, b.titleLabel.frame.size.height+30);
}
```

I am using two separate storyboards, but they are identical except for the size of the text.

Any ideas? As I mentioned at the start, it works perfectly on iPhone, just not iPad.

Comment: Why don't you use Autolayout ?

Comment: I thought about using Autolayout, but the rest of the project works perfectly using good old-fashioned storyboards. This particular screen is the only one that doesn't work as expected on an iPad, so I was hoping that I was missing something obvious.